# ¿Cómo instalar Gambas 2.0 en Linux Mint 21.1?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, visual-basic

¡Buenas a todos! Tengo instalado en una máquina virtual Linux Mint 21.1 donde he intentado abrir un proyecto antiguo que hice en Gambas 2.0, pero no he podido encontrar el programa y sólo puedo descargar Gambas 3. He intentado convertirlo a Gambas 3 y no me deja hacerlo ya que me aparecen los siguientes mensajes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que estaría muy agradecido si alguien me pudiera echar una mano para descargar Gambas 2.0 para abrir este proyecto, ya que rehacerlo en Gambas 3 me costaría mucho tiempo. Un saludo a todos y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de gambas3 usas exáctamente? Te recomiendo que actualices la  versión a través del PPA, suelen arreglarse bastantes problemas de este tipo. Así mismo, consulta el foro de **Gambas-es** (https://gambas-es.org/showthread.php?tid=948)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Gracias a ti lo he podido solucionar y ahora ya he podido abrir mi proyecto. Un saludo